# Gridstack - widget's max width bigger than grid width crashes resizing of widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

I'm using [gridstack.js](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) (v0.2.6) library for my dashboard view in web application. I tried to implement a possibility to let user change the grid width. Almost everything seems to be working, but I encountered a problem with `maxWidth` of widgets. Setting widget's `maxWidth` to bigger value than number of grid columns seems to be crashing resizing of widget. For example, when I set `gridWidth = 3` and widget's `maxWidth = 5`, I can resize widget to max ~1.3 * column width instead of 3 columns.

I provide the most important parts of code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-stack grid-stack-3">

</div>
```

**Javascript**

Initialization:

```
var $dashboard = $('.grid-stack');
var columnsNumber = 3;

function initGridStack() {
    $dashboard[0].className = "grid-stack grid-stack-" + columnsNumber;

    var options = {
        cell_height: 200,
        vertical_margin: 10,
        animate: true,
        width: columnsNumber,
        draggable: {
            handle: '.widget-header',
        }
    };
    $dashboard.gridstack(options);
```

Adding widget:

```
// ...
$widget = createWidgetElement()
$dashboard.data('gridstack').addWidget($widget, x, y, width, height, autoposition, minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, maxHeight);
```

---

**Question**

Has anybody had a similar problem and has any idea how can I handle this? I'll be grateful for any help.